# What is causing yellow spots on my cucumber seedling's leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, vegetables, leaves

I planted these cucumbers last week, and yesterday I noticed the leaves have yellow spots and edges. Do I need to buy new plants?

[image]

Comment: What have the temperatures been like where you are since you planted these? Were these plants under cover when you bought them, or out in the open? Any other info you can give would be useful, such as planting medium, sunlight levels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the result of poor [hardening off](http://www.growinggardens.org/hardening-off-plant-starts). But the scorched leaf edges in your picture don't look too bad. The plants should be fine, that damage is mostly cosmetic. Next time, let the plant's adjust more gradually.

P.S. Those hills are very close, so close that even one plant per hill could get tight. Make sure you thin properly.

Comment: Interestingly, I noticed that the patches of cucumber seedlings I didn't thin this year quite outperformed those that I did thin (they grew larger, healthier, and had more fruit). I don't know why this happened, however. Maybe it's salty soil or something (and maybe more plants were needed to use the salts), or maybe the roots fed off each other like they were one plant. Maybe it's the extra ground cover that helped. Either way, it's different from my experience with tomatoes, granted I've never grown a thick patch of tomato seedlings out (just two or three), outdoors, anyway.